# cron.hourly "exited with return code 1"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, scheduled-tasks

I'm currently on Linux Ubuntu 14.04 (I think).

So I previously had a cron.daily script which was working fine. I decided to use the same script but move it to cron.hourly and now it wont work.

/etc/cron.hourly/dstealth-watch-tv

```
#!/bin/bash

times=$(date)
echo "${times}:" >> /var/log/dstealth/watch-tv.log
/usr/bin/curl --silent http://watch.dstealth.com/tv/refreshToken.php?k=secretRefreshKey >> /var/log/dstealth/watch-tv.log
```

I've given the file CHMOD: 755

The log file was created manually with CHMOD: 644 and is empty.

Then I used:

```
service cron reload
```

and waited several hours hoping for an output into my log file but it remains empty.

I've tried

```
run-parts --verbose /etc/cron.hourly
```

and this is the output I get:

```
/etc/cron.hourly/dstealth-watch-tv:
run-parts: failed to exec /etc/cron.hourly/dstealth-watch-tv: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/cron.hourly/dstealth-watch-tv exited with return code 1
```

This also did not result in anything being input into the log file. I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. Please assist.

Comment: check your script listed by `run-parts --report --test /etc/cron.hourly -- lists `

Comment: it just lists /etc/cront.hourly/dstealth-watch-tv

Comment: May be something wrong with your script name, try to rename

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance and my apologies for the misplacement. I just love this place soo much it's always my first go-to for questions. I've posted at Unix & Linux Stack Exchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369992/cron-hourly-exited-with-return-code-1-no-output-to-log-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to guidance from JWW, I posted on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange and someone was able to answer the question almost immediately.

The script was created essentially in Windows using NppFTP so the following command was required:

```
dos2unix /etc/cron.hourly/dstealth-watch-tv
```

- Credit goes to roaima